# Error in plugin "gulp-file-include" Message: JSON5: invalid character '\r' at 1:66

Tags: gulp

I was using gulp smoothly until the task runner started showing the below error in the VS Code terminal:

[Error shown in the VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCB78.png)

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Consider adding the JSON containing error to maximize your question usefulness. hard to understand what happens without examples.

Comment: Hi there. After some head scratching hit and trial i was able to get rid of the issue. It seems to be a weird bug in VS Code in code auto formatting. The trouble was in gulp-file-include partials for bread crumbs on the page. The VS Code auto formatter was causing the long parameters name with line breaks which some how broke the gulp workflow.

Comment: To clarify further, the problem was as depicted in the below images: – 

![Line-Breaks that broke the words](https://imgur.com/xTnHRR8).

![Error in the VS Code terminal](https://imgur.com/ghuKR3V).

The fix i applied was as follows:

![My Fix](https://imgur.com/0BmvwRJ).

Answer (score 1):

I found the following code related to the "gulp-file-include" partials in my HTML code to break the task runner workflow because of code autoformat:

[Error in the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP6QJ.png)

I fixed it by putting the line-break as per following:

[The Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DDqL.png)